# one line command that prints a unique list of users running processes

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Write a one line command that prints a unique list of users running processes on the system.

Can you number them on a per-user basis?

Are there any exceptions or "gotchas" to your solution?

Comment: Please change the topic of this question to something explaining the questions, e.g. "one line command that prints a unique list of users running processes"

Comment: How is there supposed to be one correct answer to this question in current form? There are not clear parameters which should be met. Therefore I think that this question should be either edited so that it can have one single answer or made community wiki.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like someones homework to me. :-)

Anyway, here are couple of examples for solving your homewo^W problem.

Show the unique list of users running processes on the system

```
ps haeo user | sort -u
```

Show the unique list of users running processes on the system, prefixed by number of processes for that user

```
ps haeo user | sort | uniq -c
```

Same than above, but sorted by the number of processes

```
ps haeo user | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Possible exceptions/gotchas include how ps decides to display threads. Read about that from the ps man page :)